# Neos CMS: How to overwrite <title> tag in head of template

Tags: fusion, neoscms

How can I overwrite the existing title tag in the head part of my default template? I can add a new  tag but the default title tag is still there. Also I would like to add the description of the page.

**default.html:**

```
<head>
    <f:section name="meta">
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{description}">
    </f:section>
</head>
```

**root.fusion:**

```
page = Neos.Neos:Page {
    head {
        meta = Neos.Fusion:Template {
            templatePath = 'resource://Test.Package/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
            sectionName = 'meta'

            title = ${'Test | ' + q(node).property('title')}
            description = ${q(node).property('description')}
        }
```

I tried to make it according the example on the Neos CMS documentation: http://neos.readthedocs.io/en/stable/CreatingASite/RenderingCustomMarkup/AdjustingOutput.html?highlight=meta#the-head

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title tag is set by `titleTag` in `head` section of Fusion template. To overwrite it you have to do it as follows:

```
page = Neos.Neos:Page {
    head {
        titleTag = Neos.Fusion:Tag {
            tagName = 'title'
            content = ${'Test | ' + q(node).property('title')}
        }
```

You can also leave it as you have in your sample, but you have to set `titleTag` to `null`:

```
page = Neos.Neos:Page {
    head {
        titleTag = null
```